# Is it possible to retrieve a Freemarker parameter value in a directive?

Tags: java, freemarker, param, directive

I am having something similar to the following in one of my templates:

```
<#assign myVar = ${myValue}-1>
```

but Freemarker is not happy and gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" freemarker.core.ParseException:
    Encountered "{" at line 43, column 43 in myTemplate.ftl.
Was expecting one of:
    "in" ...
    ">" ...
    <EMPTY_DIRECTIVE_END> ...
    etc...
```

Is there any way I can use/retrieve the value of `myValue` and use it in a directive?

Comment: Awww.  I don't think it's worth a bad-question vote just because it's documented.  :-)  Every time I'm away from FreeMarker for a few weeks I mess this distinction up.  I think it's because it looks so Perl-y and Perl would be happy with the `${}` way everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
<#assign myVar = myValue - 1 >
```

(There's an example similar to this in [the documentation for `assign`](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_assign.html))

The `${}` syntax is used when you're outside of a FreeMarker directive and need to attract its attention to do interpolation.  Within FreeMarker tags, though, variables must be bare.